# Angular @Component in separate file of export class

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

With `angularjs` we learned to structure our code like this.

item.module.js:

```
angular.module('name', [ deps ] )
```

item.component.js

```
angular.module('name')
  .component({ declaration, controller: 'controller', template: template})
```

item.controller.js

```
angular.module('name')
  .controller('controller', code..);
```

item.html

```
   <html>
```

With `angular` however
a component is declared in a single file with it's controller

```
@Component({ templateUrl: template })
export class BlaComponent {}
```

Is there a way to put these two declarations is separate files?
Is this desired (pro's / con's)

Bonus question (i'm still googling this one): Is there any propper guide for large projects and file structure?

Comment: Reading this https://angular.io/guide/styleguide  will answer all your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Component is just a decorator that contains metadata for the class. In other words it just defines stuff for your class in a more elegant way.

> The @Component function takes the configuration object and turns it into metadata that it attaches to the component class definition. Angular discovers this metadata at runtime and thus knows how to do "the right thing".

[Read more here](https://angular.io/guide/architecture#!#metadata)

There is no controller in Angular2+, but class. In other words you don't separate decorators from the class.

Check [Official Angular 2 Styleguide Application Structure](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#application-structure-and-ngmodules) to get some idea how to structure your code. Also check the [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) project to boost your application development. Note that Angular CLI uses the Official Angular 2 Styleguide and conventions and is really convenient, plus it gives you the basic structure from where you can continue expanding your project easily.

Answer (score 1):

We're using [official style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide) in our team and we find it very suitable for our needs.

Answering your question, you cannot split `@Component` decorator from its class and you don't really have to. You may still have your templates and styles in separate files which is actually [officially recommended in this section](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#extract-templates-and-styles-to-their-own-files).